# Finding a standard matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

I'm pretty confused on this question. How would I find the standard matrix for a linear transformation like this? I thought since it is mapping a point from (x,y) -> (x,-x) the solution should have been {(1,0) , ( -1,0)} but apparently that is wrong. Any clarification would be really appreciated

Comment: It takes $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$ and then to $(-y,x)$

Comment: So then would the standard matrix be just be {(0,1) , (1,0)}?

Comment: Sorry, I read the second line as $y=x$, not $y=-x$; with the correct reading, $T$ should take $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$ and then to $(y,-x)$; so there should be a negative sign with the second $1$ in the matrix

Comment: All good, so it should then be {(0,-1) , (1,0)} right?

Comment: you can check where $T$ takes the standard basis vectors:  $(1,0)\mapsto(1,0)\mapsto(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)\mapsto(0,-1)\mapsto(1,0)$, so $A=\pmatrix{0&&1\\-1&&0}$

Comment: I watched a video recommending that idea. Is that the most intuitive idea? I really want to understand the process behind things instead of just the mechanics

Comment: the column vectors of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection through the X-axis is $$(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$$
Reflection through the line $y=-x$ is $$(x',y') \mapsto (-y',-x')$$(First drop a perpendicular from $(x',y')$ to the line $y=-x$. Call the foot $(x_*,y_*)$ Call the reflected point$(x_{**},y_{**})$Use $$x_{**}-x_*=x_*-x',y_{**}-y_*=y_*-y'$$Conclude that $$x_{**}=-y',y_{**}=-x')$$ The composite transformation is given by 
$$\begin{bmatrix}x''\\y''\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$ $$=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$